# android: showquickcontact() works great on froyo, not on eclair, which throws an ActivityNotFound exception

Tags: android, android-activity, quickcontact

I've done a lot of googling over the days and I haven't been able to get this problem solved. I'm writing an app and a widget in which I want the quick contact dialog displayed when the user clicks on an `ImageView` or some other view element by calling `QuickContact.showQuickContact()`. For some reason, every time I try on Eclair, I get the following error thrown:

> 01-02 17:51:28.869: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(657):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.sx.favwidget/com.sx.favwidget.PopupActivity}:
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=com.android.contacts.action.QUICK_CONTACT
>   dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0n4D29415739
>   flg=0x14200000 (has extras)

(I left out the rest of the logcat, but I can put it back if you guys need it)

When I try the exact same code on Froyo, it just works. I don't want to have my app targeted only for Froyo users - I'm targeting 2.1 as the minimum OS level. I've found some other people on Stack Overflow struggling with getting QuickContacts to display.

I could use a QuickContactBadge, and that does work on Eclair, but I'm not allowed a QuickContactBadge in an AppWidget, so I have do this instead. I dug through Android's source code and found the relevant XML files and code for creating the layout but I can't just easily compile it myself because it's a huge headache with all the private API calls.

Here is my code. It's simple.

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        String name = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label)).getText().toString();

        Cursor sc = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,   Contacts._ID}, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "= ?", new String[] {name}, null);

        sc.moveToFirst();          

        String lookup_key = sc.getString(sc.getColumnIndex(Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));

        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookup_key);

        QuickContact.showQuickContact(getApplicationContext(), v, uri, QuickContact.MODE_SMALL, null);

        }
}
```

It's just so strange that it works on Froyo, not Eclair, but the API call has been there since Android 2.0. Can anyone help me here??

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this as well some time ago but forgot to post how. What I did was launch a new activity that was transparent, and I got the rectangle from which the intent was launched. This activity had only a QuickContactBadge element, so I positioned it using the rectangle and performed a click action automatically on it. Once this was displayed, I finished the activity - but the badge remains. Therefore, when the person clicked out of the QuickContactBadge, they'd be right back to where they started.

I didn't get a chance to peruse your (Omegamon) code thoroughly - is your method similar to mine?

Comment: It's also worth noting that this is the same method Android uses to show its QuickContacts. After writing all the code, I looked through the source code again and found a comment (which I'm surprised I didn't notice before) saying how this was actually the current workaround until framework support is built.