# How do you get Android Intent for showing "QuickContact"?

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts, quickcontact

I'm working on my first Android application, and am trying to get an `Intent` for the `QuickContact` panel. Somewhere I had found mention of the method `QuickContact.getQuickContactIntent(...)`. But when I try to use it, it tells me that it is undefined for the type `QuickContact`. After googling for several days, I find a bunch of pages using it in code, but nothing about how to use it or what imports are necessary or anything. So how do I use this method? I need to get the `Intent` used to launch the panel.

I've included the following import in my file:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.QuickContact;
```

Alternatively, what other method could I use to get a `QuickContact` intent for passing to something expecting an intent? I am looking to pass the intent back in the cursor for a LiveFolder provider.

I am developing against the Google APIs Level 9, platform number 2.3.1. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the way I got this to work was to instead abandon the idea of using LiveFolders, and write my own "folder" dialog, to which I can add actual QuickContactBadge widgets using an adapter of my own devising.

Answer (score 0):

Use the widget `onUpdate()` and `onRecieve()` events to communicate with the `RemoteView` like explained [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435239/how-to-display-quickcontact-card-from-widget). The documented source of that discussion is [`here`](http://advback.com/android/working-with-app-widgets-android/) if you want some reading material. I can't begin to assume why you're trying to get the intent, or how you initially created the `ContactContract.QuickContact` object you're referring to. Little more information might get a few more views, and probably alternate solutions; so if this doesn't help consider posting a bit more info.

Comment: I've clarified what I'm doing with it a little. I am not sure I can communicate with the widget at all in that regard, as I am looking to pass the intent back in the cursor to a LiveFolder provider. I can't catch events to respond to in the LiveFolder itself, can I?