# Open QuickContactBadge from home screen widget Android 4+

Tags: android-widget, android-contacts

I am trying to show the Quick Contact Badge from a home screen widget which shows the favourite contact pictures in a grid layout. I went through the tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435239/how-to-display-quickcontact-card-from-widget) but still I cannot figure it out.

When I click on a contact I always get the following error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gridwidget/com.example.gridwidget.ContactBadge}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.contacts.action.QUICK_CONTACT`

despite I am calling the 'ContactsContract.QuickContact.showQuickContact();' from an activity.

This intent is causing the problem: `com.android.contacts.action.QUICK_CONTACT`

I tried to add it in my manifest file without success:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.gridwidget.ContactBadge"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_badge"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >

         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.contacts.action.QUICK_CONTACT" />
            <action android:name="com.example.gridwidget.BADGE_ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Any suggestion? Since I am showing a collection, I used the `RemoteViewsService` pattern as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The URI I was passing to `ContactsContract.QuickContact.showQuickContact()` was badly formatted.

It is working properly now